Correct singleton pattern implementation?
I have the following singleton implementation based on a video https://youtu.be/Q6HJpgdkAK8?si=k-9ksjHirLHq5Ne2 Some features of my own implementation are different, but i want to know whether my implementation is correct in general terms.
My Singleton class:
internal class CSingleton
{
    // Aquí guardamos la única instancia que va a existir.
    private static object instance;

    // Creamos el constructor privado.
    private CSingleton()
    {
        
    }

    public static object ObtenInstancia()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new COctopus();
        }

        // Aseguramos que se crea una sola vez.
        return instance;
    }

    private class COctopus
    {
        private readonly string figure = "\t\t\t\t\t           °°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t  °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t   \t         °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n                                         °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t    \t          °°°°°°°  °°°°°°°  °°°°°°°         \r\n\t\t\t  °\t             °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°     \t   \r\n\t\t\t °°\t    °         °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°       °     \r\n\t\t\t °°°\t   °°\t\t°°°°°°°°°°°°°        °°     °\r\n\t\t\t  °°°\t  °°°            °°°°°°°°°°         °°°      °°\r\n\t\t\t   °°°° \t          °°°°°°°°                   °°°\r\n\t\t\t    °°°°°\t            °°°°°\t\t     °°°\r\n\t\t\t     °°°°°\t                                    °°°°\r\n\t\t\t      °°°°°      °°°°\t     -\t   -   °°°°        °°°°°\r\n\t\t\t        °°°\t °°°       /   \\  /  \\   °°°\t   °°°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t °°°\t  |     \\/    |   °°°       °°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t  °°\t   \\         /     °°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   °°       \\       /      °°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t    °        \\     /       °\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      \\   /\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t       \\_/\t";

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format(figure);
        }
    }
} 


How do you expect to utilize it? var x = ...? You don't need extra wrapper CSingleton, which holds private class COctopus, just make COctopus' constructor private.

I expect to utilize it by accesing the method and keep the return value whitin a object variable.

Everything you need to know about singletons - https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton

Define "correct". Also, nowadays, you typically use dependency injection and define lifetime by that.

If multi-threading is a concern, your code has a race condition and would thus be not correct.

i want to know whether my implementation is correct in general terms. -- it is not correct because it is not thread safe.  The correct + best performing way is to use the built-in type Lazy<T> as shown in this answer by Gang to What is the best way to implement Singleton Design Pattern in C# with performance constraint?.  If you are working in a version before .NET 4 (unlikely!) see Singleton by Jon Skeet clarification.

Regarding dependency injection vs singletons, see Dependency Injection & Singleton Design pattern and/or Dependency Injection and/vs Global Singleton.

Your actual class which does the job can hold singleton instance, you dont need wrapper class here.
Just do:
internal class COctopus
{
    private COctopus() { }

    public static COctopus Instance { get; } = new();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Your stuff here
    }
}


I´m making sure that the COctopus class is only accesible by accessing Singleton class. I don´t want COctopus class to be accesed by other way. Is my idea correct? Thanks for your help, it really helped me!!

you also would need the class to be sealed

It's better to use double-check while creating an instance.
internal class COctopus
{
    private static volatile COctopus _instance;
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();

    private readonly string figure = "\t\t\t\t\t           °°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t  °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t   \t         °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n                                         °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°\r\n\t\t\t    \t          °°°°°°°  °°°°°°°  °°°°°°°         \r\n\t\t\t  °\t             °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°     \t   \r\n\t\t\t °°\t    °         °°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°       °     \r\n\t\t\t °°°\t   °°\t\t°°°°°°°°°°°°°        °°     °\r\n\t\t\t  °°°\t  °°°            °°°°°°°°°°         °°°      °°\r\n\t\t\t   °°°° \t          °°°°°°°°                   °°°\r\n\t\t\t    °°°°°\t            °°°°°\t\t     °°°\r\n\t\t\t     °°°°°\t                                    °°°°\r\n\t\t\t      °°°°°      °°°°\t     -\t   -   °°°°        °°°°°\r\n\t\t\t        °°°\t °°°       /   \\  /  \\   °°°\t   °°°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t °°°\t  |     \\/    |   °°°       °°°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t  °°\t   \\         /     °°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t   °°       \\       /      °°\r\n\t\t\t\t\t    °        \\     /       °\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t      \\   /\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t       \\_/\t";

     private COctopus()
     {
        
     }

     public static COctopus ObtenInstancia
     {
       get
       {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (Lock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                        _instance = new COctopus();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
     }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return String.Format(figure);
    }
}

